# Splitting text file into seperate keys in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently looking for help with understanding how to split an imported text file into separate keys and values. My current code uses the first item in the line as the key and the rest as the value e.g {1246325: '3 Chef David Jones'}.

I would like to be able to split these lines up into separate keys that I have defined such as staff code, years working, job title and name. For example {Staff code: 123456, Years: 3, Job: Chef, Name: David Jones}. but I would like to keep the information for each person grouped and separate for other information so I can add code to search for specific piece of information and it will obtain everyone matching that criteria.

```
dict={}


def load_file(filename):

f = open(filename, "r")
line = f.readline()
for line in f:
    splitLine = line.split()
    dict[int(splitLine[0])] = " ".join(splitLine[1:])
f.close()

print(dict)
if __name__ == "__main__":
        filename = input("Enter Filename: ")
```

I'm just looking for a push in the right direction I understand people come here asking for entire code to be wrote for them but I'm just asking for help with my problem, thank you.

Comment: Pandas in python is a very good library for this purpose..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds a lot like you're trying to read a CSV. [Fortunately, there's a Python to help with that.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Your code would look something like this, assuming your fields are space delimited:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=' ')
    for line in reader:
       print(line)
```

`reader` then contains a dict of keys to values, using the first row to get the names. So, if your file looks like

```
ID Years Name
234234 3 John
314888 10 Sally
```

then `reader` after that would contain

```
[{'ID': '234234', 'Years': '3', 'Name': 'John'},
 {'ID': '314888', 'Years': '10', 'Name': 'Sally'}]
```

(Note it's not actually a list, so you have to access it with a for loop.)

Comment: Yes, I get this would be better as a comment, but until I get enough rep, that's not happening. Hopefully this can at least help Peter.

Comment: Posting answers that you know should be comments is not a good way to gain rep. [Link-only answers aren't useful.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) Please remove this or edit it into a proper answer.